# SQL query for distinct user/date with additional columns

Tags: sql, distinct

I have a table of sessions with an agent, the start time of the session, and how many people they helped. I'd like to query to see the totals of each agent/date combo, combining all the sessions for that day. For example, I have:

```
Agent 1 - 1/8/13 11:30am - 8
Agent 2 - 1/8/13 11:32am - 9
Agent 1 - 1/8/13 12:45pm - 10
Agent 2 - 1/9/13 10:20am - 8
Agent 3 - 1/9/13 11:45am - 7
```

And what I'd like to see is:

```
1/8/13 - Agent 1 - 18
1/8/13 - Agent 2 - 9
1/9/13 - Agent 2 - 8
1/9/13 - Agent 3 - 7
```

What I tried was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(CHAR(10), StartTime, 101) as 'Day',
       Agent,
       Helped
FROM Sessions
```

But I understand now that DISTINCT is going to return unique results for all columns selected, so I'll just see the original data, not combined by day. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: agent 2 maybe 17 u need or 9 ??

Answer (score 3):

What you want here is the [aggregate `SUM()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) grouped by `Agent` and day.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), StartTime, 101) as 'Day',
       Agent,
       SUM(Helped) AS Helped
FROM Sessions
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), StartTime, 101),
         Agent
```

I cannot remember if SQL Server will allow you to use the alias `Day` in the `GROUP BY`. If it does, you can do

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), StartTime, 101) as 'Day',
       Agent,
       SUM(Helped) AS Helped
FROM Sessions
GROUP BY Day, Agent,
```

Comment: No, you can't use the Day alias in the `group by` (but you could in an `order by`)

Comment: @PaulWilliams Thanks - too much MySQL this year, and not much MSSQL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `GROUP BY` the StartTime and the Agent and `SUM` up the Helped:

```
declare @Sessions table
(
    StartTime datetime,
    Agent varchar(50),
    Helped int
)

insert into @Sessions (Agent, StartTime, Helped)
select 'Agent 1', '1/8/13 11:30am', 8
union select 'Agent 2', '1/8/13 11:32am', 9
union select 'Agent 1', '1/8/13 12:45pm', 10
union select 'Agent 2', '1/9/13 10:20am', 8
union select 'Agent 3', '1/9/13 11:45am', 7

select
    convert(varchar(10), StartTime, 101) as [Day],
    Agent,
    sum(Helped)
from
    @sessions
group by
    convert(varchar(10), StartTime, 101),
    Agent
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if it's too simple... but seems like the answer you need..

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/613af/15)

Query:

```
SELECT date as times,
       id,
       sum(items)
FROM agents
group by id, date
;
```

Results:

```
|      TIMES |      ID | COLUMN_2 |
-----------------------------------
| 2013-01-08 | Agent 1 |       18 |
| 2013-01-08 | Agent 2 |        9 |
| 2013-01-09 | Agent 2 |        8 |
| 2013-01-09 | Agent 3 |        7 |
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you will want to explore the 'group by' command - something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), StartTime, 101) as 'Day',
   Agent,
   Helped
FROM Sessions GROUP BY (Agent) order by Agent asc
```

Comment: you need to group by 'day' as well (probably the formula used to stip the time).